# Java - Printf Broken When Space Encountered For ASCII Conversion

Tags: java, printf, ascii

I have a script that is supposed to take a String of both numbers and letters and break them down into their `ASCII/Hex` values under the appropriate column. It works flawlessly until I put a space anywhere in the String. It will print everything normally up to the space and then break with no errors.

```
Ex. (works):
kdillon76

Ex. (does NOT work):
kdillon 76
```

In my For Loop I have an If Statement stating that if the character is a digit then "do this" followed by an Else Statement to cover anything "else". Shouldn't the Else Statement be able to translate the space to the "32" ASCII number?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
  import java.util.*; // Load all Utility Classes

public class DKUnit3Ch12 { // Begin Class DKUnit3Ch12

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Begin Main

        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in); // Initialize the Scanner
        String myInput; // Define a new Variable

        System.out.print("Please enter a string of any length: "); //Print the text
        myInput = myScan.next(); // Define a new Variable with the next user input

        System.out.printf("%n%-8s%-16s%-16s%s%n", "Initial", "ASCII(char)", "ASCII(int)", "Hex"); // Print the labels with proper tablature

        for(int x = 0; x < myInput.length(); x++) { // Begin For Loop

            char myChar = myInput.charAt(x); // Define a new Variable based on position in index
            if(Character.isDigit(myChar)) { // Begin If Statement (if the character is a digit)
                System.out.printf("%-24s%-16d%02X%n", myChar, (int)myChar, (int)myChar); // Print the items with proper tablature including capitalized Hex
            } // End If Statement
            else { // Begin Else Statement (if the character is NOT a digit)
                System.out.printf("%-8s%-32d%02X%n", myChar, (int)myChar, (int)myChar);  // Print the items with proper tablature including capitalized Hex
            } // End Else Statement

        } // End For Loop

        System.out.print("\nThank you for playing!"); // Print the text

        myScan.close(); // Close the Scanner

    } // End Main

} // End Class DKUnit3Ch12
```

Comment: "Shouldn't the Else Statement be able to translate the space to the "32" ASCII number?": You should understand that Java doesn't use ASCII. See the [Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: I understand that, but at the time I thought that the Else Statement would have caught anything that wasn't a Digit and found its ASCII value. I'm definitely saving that link you provided for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand what I was doing wrong here:
"myScan.next()" will only return what comes before the space whereas "myScan.nextLine()" bumps the Scanner down after returning the current line. Would I also have been able to find the ASCII Value by using the "Character.isWhitespace()" method (albeit with more code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `myScan.next()` with `myScan.nextLine()`

Comment: Nailed it. I'm new to Java and it seems like there are TONS of little things like these that I miss. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

`A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.`